# Delete duplicated wp_postmeta record

Tags: posts, post-meta

I have many duplicated wp_postmeta record (about hundreds record with same post_id & meta_key)  and need to delete safely via mysql, is there any effective way to delete the postmeta record.

[image: wp_postmeta table]

Further question is how to create code implementation to prevent this postmeta duplication. Many Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite complicates grouped request, so to avoid problems, consider to use [Cleanup Duplicate Meta](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cleanup-duplicate-meta/) plugin.

The reason why duplicate entries are occured is usage of `add_post_meta()`. Just use `update_post_meta()` (even to create meta, it works) - and you will have always one meta field with certain name per post.

Comment: That plugin saved me hours of work thanks! still working today

Answer (score 4):

Try it to delete duplicated wp_postmeta record:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_id` NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(`pm`.`meta_id`) FROM `wp_postmeta` pm GROUP BY `pm`.`post_id`, `pm`.`meta_key`) x)
```

Use `update_post_meta` instead of `add_post_meta` to prevent create duplicate postmeta.