# delete duplicates wp_postmeta

Tags: post-meta, duplicates

I'm looking to cleanup wp_postmeta. I've found dozens of duplicate entries.

I've spend about 8 hours looking through topics and trying code and plugins to no avail.

The most useful article on the subject I found is [this.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/262038/delete-duplicated-wp-postmeta-record)

However the article is from 5 years ago and I'm not sure that the suggested code leaves at least 1 entry from each duplicate. Also the plugin that is suggested (Cleanup Duplicate Meta) is exactly what I need, but it hasn't been updated for 7 years. The plugin tells me there are over a million duplicates, but when I click to clean it up, nothing happens.

Can someone confirm that

```
DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_id` NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(`pm`.`meta_id`) FROM `wp_postmeta` pm GROUP BY `pm`.`post_id`, `pm`.`meta_key`) x)
```

will delete the duplicates but leave at least 1 entry of each?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
DELETE t1 FROM wp_postmeta t1, wp_postmeta t2 
WHERE t1.meta_id > t2.meta_id 
AND t1.meta_key = t2.meta_key 
AND t1.post_id = t2.post_id
```

Comment: I had to have my hosting provider do the operation as the connection to the server was timing out when I tried it. The query took 4h to complete, but at least so far it looks to be a resounding success. Can't find anything broken with the website. Thank you so much. Went from 1.5mil to only 60k entries!!! Now it's just a question of wtf was creating all of this bloat.

Comment: @Daniel Please select my answer as correct if it helped you :)